# scanf is not working as expected

Tags: c++, c, printf, scanf

i want to take 3 inputts from user age, gender(m/f), marital status(m/u).
i used char data type for gender and marital status. here is the code below..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

main() {
int age;
char gender,marital_status;
printf("Enter your age: ");
scanf("%d",&age);
printf("Enter your gender (m/f): ");    
scanf("%c",&gender);
printf("\nEnter your marital status (m/u): ");      
scanf("%c",&marital_status);


}
```

age part works corectly, i.e it takes age from user and store it to age. But after that both below printf statements displayed at once. How to display them one by one to take input from user as gender and marital status.

Comment: How is this `C++`, when the `C I/O library` is used throughout?

Comment: Minor: Suggest last prompt change "\nEnter your marital status(m/u): ".  (I was wondering what `u` meant in "Enter your gender (m/u)" :-)

Comment: "u" meant un_married :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `%c` accepts `'\n'` symbol that's left over from entering the age. You would be better off reading into a string, and taking the first character, like this:

```
char buf[2];
printf("Enter your gender (m/f): ");
scanf("%1s", buf);
gender = buf[0];
printf("\nEnter your marital status (m/u): ");
scanf("%1s", buf);
marital_status = buf[0];
```

The `%s` format specifier is set up to ignore all whitespace. Note the one character limit after `%` in the format specifier.

Comment: both are storing in buff[0] location?

Comment: `"%1s"` is fine, though wonder why not suggest `" %c"`?  Maybe there is an unseen insight.

Comment: `if((marital_status=="m")||((marital_status=="u")&&(age>30))||((gender=="f")&&(age>25)‌​)) { printf("You are insured"); }`
can u please tell what is the problem in if statement?

Comment: @sam Since `marital_status` is `char`, you need to compare it with a `char` literal, not a string literal (i.e. use single quotes, not double quotes). Moreover, string literals are not compared this way as well - if you want to compare strings, use `strcmp` function.